# How to download 64-bit pip packages under 32-bit environment

Tags: python, tensorflow, 32bit-64bit

I am trying to install tensorflow via pip under 64-bit environment which doesn't allow to use internet connection(isolated local network) and external devices such as USB neither. Fortunately, I have 32-bit internet connected environment and there is a network connection between 32-bit and 64-bit environment via a local secured network, so I can transfer data from 32-bit env. to 64-bit env.

As far as I know, the easiest way to download a package with its dependencies is `pip3 download tensorflow`. However, pip(32-bit) doesn't have the tensorflow package since the current tensorflow package is only supported by 64-bit.

Therefore, I am downloading each required dependency for tensorflow one by one, but it is very inefficient way to do.

Is there any clever way to perform this tasks?

Answer (score 0):

Just download the correct wheel for your platform directly from the one of the Tensorflow PyPI pages:

- [Without GPU support or OS X](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tensorflow)
- [With GPU support](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tensorflow-gpu) (no OS X package variant)

The OS X version includes GPU support and is distributed as `tensorflow`, not `tensorflow-gpu`.

You'll need to select one of the `.whl` files listed there, based on your Python version (2.7, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5 or 3.6) and OS (Windows, OS X or Linux). All wheels listed there are compiled for 64-bit.

Once downloaded onto your 32-bit environment and transferred to the 64-bit machine, use `pip install <filename>` to install the wheel.